# Applescript not executing with user input

Tags: applescript

I have a simple Applescript that enters a phone number along with a standard message. The script was operating as intended when I hardcoded a phone number. I tried to expand it to take user input, it now gives a workflow completed but the message isn't keystroked. 
It works as intended when running in the Automator window, but that's the only place where it works.

End Goal: To be able to run this Applescript in any application and the message is keystroked.

```
set phoneNumber to "error"
set contactName to (choose from list {"John", "Bob", "Jill"} with prompt "Who do you want to contact?") as string

if contactName is "John" then
    set phoneNumber to "(310) 213-1234"
else if contactName is "Bob" then
    set phoneNumber to "(213) 123-1234"
else if contactName is "Jill" then
    set phoneNumber to "(424) 456-7890"
end if

set theMessage to "Hi, please contact " & contactName & " at: " & phoneNumber & return & "Thank you."
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke theMessage
end tell
```

[Screenshot of workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXZ6o.png)

Comment: Your missing the closing parenthesis on the `set contactName ...` line of _code_. Also, what's with as the unnecessary parentheses throughout and 5 occurrences of `as string` when only one is needed at the end of the `set contactName ...` line of _code_. [See this example of a less verbose and more clean version of your code.](https://paste.ee/p/MAf0f) That said, where do you expect the output of the `keystroke` _command_ to go as you've not set focus to a text field outside of the Automator action? I'd suggest you clarify what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks! Added the missing parenthesis, I have it my applescript, but mistyped it while re-entering here. Appreciate the cleaner version.

Comment: BTW Note that the example code does not contain any error handling around the set `contactName ...` line of code as it should in case Cancel is chosen. Also it is still not clear what you're really trying to do, I'll repeat... "That said, where do you expect the output of the keystroke command to go as you've not set focus to a text field outside of the Automator action? I'd suggest you clarify what it is you're trying to do."

Comment: I want the short script to run after I focus the input field. I use this message in multiple places and the input field isn't always on the same place on a page. Sometimes it's on a web page sometimes in an email. I have it set up as a macro so I can run it wherever I need to enter the message.

Comment: The workflow is reporting it's completed but the message is never keystroked. I am confused why it runs without the 'set contactName'  portion as intended.

Comment: Your question, as currently written, basically is not answerable. You have already been told what was wrong with what you originally posted as well as shown a much better way to write the code (sans error handling)! SO is not a code writing service! You should show us the code that's not working for you. Have a look at, [How to create a Minimal, Complete,and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can help fix your code that's not working for you. Since this is also part of an Automator workflow you should also include a screenshot of the entire workflow.

Comment: You also said, "I tried to expand it to take user input and now it throws an error but I'm unsure how to debug it." Without seeing what you have, how do you expect we help fix it!? That's what [How to create a Minimal, Complete,and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is for! You also said, "It works as intended when running in the Automator window, but that's the only place where it works." but that contradicts the previous statement along with the code you posted!

Comment: I attached a screenshot of my workflow file. It works as intended when the phone number is hardcoded but doesn't work with the contactName line. I added additional information, I hope it makes more sense as what my goal is.

Comment: Looking at the image of Automator, I can see the highlighting around the Run AppleScript action, which mean no editable text field has focus. System Events can only `keystroke` something to an editable text field, therefore you **must** set focus to where you want the keystrokes sent first! Because you're using a list box, the focus will aways be taken away from whatever had focus prior to the list box being displayed. Therefore, you my first ascertain what has focus, store info about it, before any code that steals focus runs, then after the selection is made, set focus back, then keystroke.

Comment: That said, I'd choose to put the message on the clipboard and paste it into the target. That is more efficient then keystroking the message. You also should add error handling so if you choose the Cancel button on the list box, it errors out quietly.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your help. I apologize the initial question posed wasn't to the point. 

I appreciate your patience, time and assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an *example* of how I might code it within a **Run AppleScript** *action*, as an **Automator Service**:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "System Events"
        --  # Get the name of the App that has focus when this Service is triggered.
        set activeApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true
        delay 0.5 
    end tell

    tell current application
        activate -- # Set focus back to me so the list box is frontmost.
        set contactName to (choose from list {"John", "Bob", "Jill"} with prompt "Who do you want to contact?") as string
        if return is false then return --   # User clicked Cancel or pressed Esc, exit the run handler.
        if contactName is "John" then
            set phoneNumber to "(310) 213-1234"
        else if contactName is "Bob" then
            set phoneNumber to "(213) 123-1234"
        else if contactName is "Jill" then
            set phoneNumber to "(424) 456-7890"
        end if
        set the clipboard to "Hi, please contact " & contactName & " at: " & phoneNumber & linefeed & "Thank you."
    end tell

    --  # Set focus back to the App that was frontmost when the Service was triggered.
    tell application activeApp
        activate
        delay 1 --  # Make sure the App has come frontmost before pasting what's on the clipboard.
        tell application "System Events"
            try
                -- # Insure the front window is indeed active.
                perform action "AXRaise" of window 1 of application process activeApp
                delay 0.2
            end try
            try
                --  # Paste from the clipboard.
                keystroke "v" using command down
                delay 0.2
            end try
        end tell
    end tell

    --  # Clear the clipboard.
    tell current application to set the clipboard to ""

end run
```

<sub>**Note:** The `delay` *commands* may or may not be necessary and or their *value* may need to be adjusted for your system. You can always remove those you find you don't need, however I feel they are strategically located and would leave them in.</sub>